# What can I do when I can't move in Minecraft on my Android and Hide GUI/HUD is already turned off?

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I open up my Minecraft account and I can change between blocks and swords, and my hotbar is there, but my movement controls are gone and I can't move anywhere.  I have turned off HUD but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I’m guessing you have your buttons set to some insanely small size for some reason. Go to settings > Touch Controls and then set the button size to something higher.